# ¿Como puedo hacer para "refrescar" la carpeta donde el proyecto guarda imagenes?

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse

en resumen:

Un usuario sube una imagen a la pagina

La imagen se guarda correctamente en una carpeta y su ruta en la base de datos mysql

El cambio no se ve reflejado en eclipse (este es el problema)

Estoy haciendo una pagina web trabajando con springboot para el back-end y tengo este metodo:

```
public PostModel save(String title, String text, String hashtags, MultipartFile[] images, UserModel user) {
        PostModel newPost = new PostModel();
        List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MultipartFile image : images) {
            String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + image.getOriginalFilename();
            Path filePath = Paths.get(uploadDir + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + fileName);
            System.out.println(filePath+"");
            try {
                Files.write(filePath, image.getBytes());
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String imageUrl = "/uploads/images/" + fileName;
            System.out.println(imageUrl);
            imageUrls.add(imageUrl);
        }
        newPost.setTitle(title);
        newPost.setText(text);
        newPost.setHashtags(hashtags);
        newPost.setPublishDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        newPost.setUser(user);
        newPost.setImagesUrl(imageUrls);
        return postRepository.save(newPost);
    }
```

para guardar las imagenes en una carpeta del proyecto mismo y las rutas de esas imagenes en una base de datos mysql.

Las imagenes se guardan correctamente en dicha carpeta, pero el cambio no se ve reflejado en eclipse (donde esta la carpeta) a no ser que reinicie la aplicacion. Cuando reinicio la aplicacion, se actualiza la carpeta y ahi si ya se puede mostrar la imagen en el front end.

La carpeta en cuestion es: demo\src\main\resources\uploads\images y es donde guardaria cualquier archivo subido por usuarios.

Como el cambio no se ve reflejado cuando se sube la imagen, cuando queiro mostrarla en la pagina me tira error 404 not found, por mas que la imagen **si** este en la carpeta, pero como no aparece en la carpeta de eclipse (a no ser que resetee la app) no la encuentra.

Puedo actualizar la carpeta instantaneamente despues de guardar una imagen? o resetear la app automaticamente cuando se sube una imagen? aunque esto ultimo no me parece lo adecuado(? tal vez la solucion va por otro lado que no estoy viendo.

Comment: Está en la carpeta donde tienes el código pero está en la carpeta del build?? Si usas springboot imagino que estarás usando maven, al hacer un build copiará los archivos estáticos... Es lo que imagino, porque sin más datos ni saber cómo tienes configurado el proyecto es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Estoy usando maven. Las imagenes en cuestion estan en una sola carpeta (src\main\resources\uploads\images) que cree yo.
tengo entendido que la carpeta static es para recursos que va a utilizar la pagina como logos o imagenes que van a estar siempre ahi no? y para almacenar imagenes subidas por usuarios cree esa carpeta aparte.
lo que hice ahora fue: windows -> general -> workspace: tildar 'Refresh using native hooks or polling' lo cual si, logra que se carguen las imagenes correctamente, aunque un poco lento. Pero debe haber una mejor solucion, no?

Comment: La mejor solución es no correr un programa de manera definitiva dentro del propio eclipse. Por qué no construyes el proyecto y lo ejecutas sin eclipse de por medio?? Has probado? Normalmente solo se ejecutan los proyectos en eclipse durante la fase de desarrollo... no en producción.

Comment: Cree y ejecute un jar. Copia las imágenes de src\main\resources\uploads\images a target\classes\uploads\images. al publicar con el jar en ejecucion, no se encunetra la carpeta donde tiene que guardarlas.
Estoy aprendiendo springboot y react, pero no he encontrado guias, ni videos sobre mi problema en particular.
Lo mas parecido a mi problema que encontre es [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67868276/unable-to-access-uploaded-image-from-react-front-end-to-spring-boot-back-end)
Mi proyecto: [enlace](https://github.com/QueenNixu/spring-boot-web-page)